# Assimp SimpleOpenGL example Linker errors

Tags: c, linker-errors, assimp

I'm trying to get the sample "SimpleOpenGl" from Assimp to work, but I get some linker errors i can't solve. (And yes I am very new)

I get 12 LNK2001 errors (below is two of them)
`1>Sample_SimpleOpenGL.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _aiTransformVecByMatrix4
    1>Sample_SimpleOpenGL.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _aiImportFile`

When googling "aiTransformVecByMatrix4" it says that it requires cimport, but it is already included, so I am not sure why I am getting this error.

The sample project can be found here: http://assimp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/assimp/trunk/samples/SimpleOpenGL/

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

[image: As you can see the cimport seems to be correct included]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have downloaded assimp, you must have its libraries in any place on your disk. Open your sample properties dialog, select Linker and check the path to external references.

This must give you a clue about where the sample is looking for libraries.

If you are not sure, please post your values so I can help you

Comment: Hi Manuel.
Thank you. I had included the lib from the VC++ directories tab, but that did not work. I included it under additional libraries under the linker settings instead. So it seems like it is working. Now I have to just read a file, and I get into trouble again :/ If I want to pass a filename to a function, how do i define it? I tried like this:
    const std::string pFile = "cube.obj";

Comment: The question is what does the function expects:

Comment: If the called function is something like this 'myfunction( const char * xx )' you must do a) from your pFile: 'myfunction( pFile.c_str() );' or b) just a constant 'myfunction( "cube.obj" );'

Comment: Then function expects it like this:
    bool DoTheImportThing( const std::string& pFile)

Comment: Hello, I couldn`t have a look before. I suppose you have moved but in any case:

Comment: bool DoTheImportThing expects a string reference (string&) so you just have to pass a string object (pFile): 'DoTheImportThing(pFile);'